# How can I compile my project with c++20 with an OpenCV dependency?

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, g++, c++20

I am trying to build my project with the c++20 flag on g++-11. My project depends on some headers in opencv.hpp from OpenCV 4.0, and now I'm getting compiler errors from these header files. I can't tell from OpenCV's docs if they support compiling with the c++20 flag. Where can I find that info?

Also is there a way to get around these errors? How could I compile their code with an older c++ standard?, but my code with c++20?

Here's a snippet of the compiler error that I'm seeing:

```
In file included from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:3724,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:59,
                 from /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /my_project/include/amp_ffmpeg/decoder.hpp:3,
                 from /my_project/src/decoder.cpp:1:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp: In constructor ‘cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(const cv::Mat&)’:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:88:57: error: arithmetic between different enumeration types ‘cv::_InputArray::KindFlag’ and ‘cv::AccessFlag’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-enum-enum-conversion]
   88 | inline _InputArray::_InputArray(const Mat& m) { init(MAT+ACCESS_READ, &m); }
      |                                                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp: In constructor ‘cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(const std::vector<cv::Mat>&)’:
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:89:83: error: arithmetic between different enumeration types ‘cv::_InputArray::KindFlag’ and ‘cv::AccessFlag’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-enum-enum-conversion]
   89 | inline _InputArray::_InputArray(const std::vector<Mat>& vec) { init(STD_VECTOR_MAT+ACCESS_READ, &vec); }
```

Comment: 30 seconds of googling mate: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20269

Comment: I saw that on my search, but didn't see a clear solution.

Comment: what's preventing you from building the library as it's supposed to be built, and then using the library in your C++20 code? is anything forcing you to build all libraries as C++20?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I think the issue is that there is code in the header that needs to get compiled. Like inline functions and such. And so that code doesn't compiled until it is included in your project.

Comment: I think in GCC there is the flag `-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion` to turn off the warning.